# Request-URI Too Long

Tags: url, nginx, long-integer

I hope someone can help me!!! Im having an issue with my wordpress website!

When I write the url of my web site www.pratoinerbasintetica.it appears this error:

Request-URI Too Long

The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

Apache Server at virtualhost.46.252.201.1 Port 80

It's like 3 days that's still doing this.

4-5 days ago I found a written "nginx" on header and was strange cause I didn't do it!!!
I don't know if this is the cause of this problem!

Please someone can help me??

Thank you

Alberto

Comment: It appears like you've got some kind of redirect loop going there. Comment out this piece of javascript on line 125 of your index page:
   location.href = 'http://pratoinerbasintetica.it/?wpdmact=process&did='+res;

and see what happens

Comment: Yes, still doing this by days, I was thinking about a problem with server but godaddy says that is a problem with some code!! I have not idea how to fix it!!!

Comment: Now that i've looked at it in a bit more detail, your problem lies with the implementation of this function: InitateFrameRequest. Comment out the line where it is called ( Line 196 ) and the redirect loop will stop

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a redirect loop on your index page and from a first glance it appears to be caused by this piece of Javascript on around line 196:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    InitiateFrameRequest();
</script>
```

Comment out the "InitiateFrameRequest()" and see if the problem still occurs.

I think your issue is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499689/website-is-redirecting-to-www1-mysite-com-why

It seems like there is some malicious Javascript code being injected into your page ( In a theme perhaps ? )

Comment: Sorry but I cant find it! where Can I find the 125 line? in which page? Thank you

Comment: You will have to search your code base for "InitiateFrameRequest()". Unfortunatly I cannot tell from the outside where this line of code would be. If you are on Linux you could try grep'ing for it: grep -R 'InitiateFrameRequest();'. Otherwise you could try an editor like Crimson Editor (free) that allows you to do a search of an entire code tree

Comment: I think your issue is related to this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499689/website-is-redirecting-to-www1-mysite-com-why

Comment: I have to find out from the theme? Im using wordpress based in linux!

Comment: Try the advice in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499689/website-is-redirecting-to-www1-mysite-com-why and see if it helps. These two issues does seem related